# In React, can i update one state depending on two other states inside a useEffect with dependencies on those two states?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a form so far just two fields, email and password and one button. Both inputs are state and validated, so i have state.email,isValid and state.pw.isValid.

I want to control the Submit button so that its active only if both email and password are valid. I read that because of how React schedules state updates its possible when using more than one state, you might not get the most current state and useEffect can ensure this.

So my question is, can i set up a state.form.isValid to control access to the submit button and update this
(
setFormIsValid(state.email.isValid && state.pw.isValid)
)
inside a useEffect with dependencies [state.email.isValid, state.password.isValid]?

So Im updating one state depending on two other states.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 text fields. Logically thinking, only one field will be updated at a time (unless it is a bot filling the text field). So, the state updates in this specific case will mostly happen one after the other and you are almost guaranteed to get the latest state always.

Unless there are other factors affecting the component, adding useEffect and then setting a new state in this useEffect based on the dependencies might be overkill.

Each setState triggers a render. So, if it is not absolutely necessary, new state setting based on 2 other states is not require.

Comment: Thanks Shahin. Yes this form only has two input fields 
 so yes probably overkill. Would the same be true if I had many input fields and I only wanted the submit button available if ALL the fields were validated? (The concern is there could be delays in React scheduling.)

Comment: Unless the user can fill up the form blazingly fast (faster than the state update can happen), all the state updates happen one after the other. So, this shouldnt be a concern for you.

Because, in case of input fields the states are updated after a user interaction and user interaction takes a finite amount of time.

The time you need to consider batching effects of state updates is when the state update is based on some code behaviour in the same execution flow (like a single click or user input causing two states to update)